# Easiest way to rename an event handler in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Since the binding between handler method and nib file is done graphically, what's the easiest way to rename my handler in Xcode without breaking that event handling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the name of your method in your .h or .m file, select `Refactor -> Rename...`. This also takes care of your XIBs.

Comment: Thanks I should have think about it but I'm not accustomed to Mac yet and so to right-click by using ctrl key :)

Answer (score 1):

1. select `-functionName:`
2. right click->refactor->rename
3. ????
4. Profit